# Get file name from input type file Angular2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, html-input

I want get the file name from my html input tag in a modal view and save it using Angular2. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do next:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)" />
```

TypeScript:

```
fileEvent(fileInput: Event){
    let file = fileInput.target.files[0];
    let fileName = file.name;
}
```

Comment: and how to get file ext?

Comment: For those getting ```Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'``` check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932086/4281182

Comment: i'm getting filename undefined.

Comment: @SelçukCihan Thanks mate. Your comment saves my life.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a more elegant option:

HTML:

```
<input #file type="file" (change)="updateFile(file)">
```

Script:

```
updateFile(file: HTMLInputElement) {
  let name = file.value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="imgFileInput.click()">Add</button>
    {{ imgFileInput?.files[0]?.name }}
<input hidden type="file" #imgFileInput (change)="uploadSingle($event)"/>
```

**Component**

```
uploadSingle(event) {
  const fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: This is totally unnecessary. A label with the for attribute will do the job without catching any clicks. Also I'm not completely sure you can trigger a click on a hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

Script

```
onFileChange(event) {    
     let files = event.target.files[0].name;
}
```

Comment: How to get file path?

Comment: You can', It's a security feature in modern browsers.
this can help, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Answer (score 1):

This work form me:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="detectFiles($event)">
<div class="output">Seleccionado: {{ fileName }} </div>
```

**TS**

```
selectedFiles: FileList;
fileName: string;

detectFiles(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    this.fileName = this.selectedFiles[0].name;
    console.log('selectedFiles: ' + this.fileName );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This link's https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932086/4281182 solution suggested by @ Selçuk Cihan did not help 
so my workaround was to make the fileInput param type "any" by doing this

```
fileEvent(fileInput){
    let file = fileInput.target.files[0];
    let fileName = file.name;
}
```

so in TS runtime this is a pure JS code

Anyways thanks for this great ans it saved me a lot of time