# How to get the file name,modified date of the uploaded file in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

Html File:

```
<label class="import-file">
   <input type="file"  accept=".doc,.pdf" hidden required>
</label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481746/get-file-name-from-input-type-file-angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the modified date:

```
let modifiedDate= file.lastModifiedDate;
```